# How to avoid unicode errors from DataFrame to CSV?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, python-unicode

Cannot get rid of unicode erros, how do i deal with them?

I'm using Dataframe (to_csv method) but the problem it shows on CSV the following:

```
GÃ²tic
MontjuÃ¯c
```

How to avoid it in Dataframes? Python 2.7 + Pandas

I'm using:

```
# encoding=utf8
```

I've tried:

```
.encode('utf-8')
u''.join(variable)
```

Comment: What should be the ideal output? Please show how it looks like in DataFrame?

Comment: Gòtic and Montjuïc should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, change the `encoding` to `latin-1`

```
df.to_csv('your_csv_name.csv', encoding = 'latin-1')
```

output:

```
Gòtic
Montjuïc
```

Works fine for me in Python 3.7

Comment: For me too in Python 2.7 thank you so much buddy, you saved my life